# What manga chapter is episode 219 of Naruto Shippuden from?

Tags: naruto

What manga chapter is episode 219 of Naruto Shippuden from? I think there are differences between the manga and the anime and I want to check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Episode 219 is towards the end of the [Fourth shinobi world war: countdown](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Countdown)

This arc lasted from volume 52 to 55. Or chapter 484 to 515.

IIRC they covered roughly 2 chapters per episode during this arc. Leading me to believe that episode 219 should match chapter 493-494